# running a python script from the terminal

Tags: python, windows

I have python installed but get an error when I want to run ez_setup.py.
I am following: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/

So I can install the setuptools and pip.

Please see the screenshot of my python terminal with the script. the script is located in the same folder as python.exe

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it like this:

```
C:\Users\CatGirl> python.exe ez_setup.py
```

`python.exe` is the Python executable which can take the name of a script as an argument. In your case this argument is `ez_setup.py`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can run a python script from the python interpreter:

**Direct call:**

you can directly call the python interpreter with the script path as argument

```
C:\path\to\python.exe mycode.py
```

**Import:**

If the script is in the current working directory or in python path, you could import the script

```
import mycode
```

Note that the script will be executed in it own namespace in this case.

**execfile:**

You can use execfile to execute the script

```
execfile("C:\path\to\mycode.py")
```